# Function return value through dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to pass some variables into function, and this function should return `sum(price)`.

I know that dynamic SQL can not be executed in a function. Thus, I write dynamic SQL in a stored procedure, then exec that stored procedure from the function.

It turned out be wrong and throws an error:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC'

Here is the function

```
create function myFunc 
    (@var1 varchar(100), 
     @var2 varchar(100), 
     @var3 varchar(100))
as
begin
    declare @t table (col float)

    insert into @t(col) 
        exec mySP @var1, @var2, @var3

    return (select col from @t)
end
```

Here is the stored procedure called by the function

```
create procedure mySP 
    @var1 varchar(100), 
    @var2 varchar(100), 
    @var3 varchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @cmd nvarchar(max) = 'select sum(price) from ' + @var1 + ' where ' + @var2 + ' = ' + @var3
    exec @cmd
end
```

I wondered how to solve the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't call a SP from a function. Just use the SP as it is. Although you should be using [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and passing your value parameter in.

Comment: The fact you want to do this leads me to suspect you have an XY problem...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DaleK. How can I receive the value from SP?

Comment: Output parameter, resultset... check the docs

Comment: Deserves downvotes for those meaningless parameter names. Make an effort!

Answer (score 2):

Quite *why* you want to do this in the first place is unclear, most likely there is a design flaw here.

**But if you want to return a value from dynamic SQL you can use an `OUTPUT` parameter.**

> You should also pass through `@var3` as a paramter, and the table and column name should be quoted using `QUOTENAME`

```sql
create or alter proc mySP
  @var1 sysname, @var2 sysname, @var3 varchar(100)
as
  
declare @cmd nvarchar(max) = '
select @retVal = sum(price)
from ' + quotename(@var1) + '
where ' + quotename(@var2) + ' = @var3;
';

declare @retVal decimal(18,2);

exec sp_executesql
  @cmd,
  N'@var3 varchar(100), @retVal decimal(18,2)',
  @var3 = @var3,
  @retVal = @retVal OUTPUT;

select @retVal;

go
```

Comment: Thank you. I did it you way but failed. It seems that here is some error about @reaVal OUTPUT variable.

Comment: What failed exactly, what error message do you have? Remember you cannot call a stored procedure from a functionm and you cannot execute dynamic SQL from a function either, you need to do this only with a stored procedure

Comment: I add `@retVal OUTPUT` after `create or alter proc mySP
  @var1 sysname, @var2 sysname, @var3 varchar(100)`, and it works. Thank you